# More than one export was found that matches the constraint exception with MEF ImportMany

Tags: c#, mef

I'm trying to debug an assembly import issue on a WPF app that uses MEF to load some plugins and looking for ideas to solve this particular exception:

> More than one export was found that matches the constraint:
>   ContractName MarkPad.Contracts.ISpellingService
>   RequiredTypeIdentity MarkPad.Contracts.ISpellingService

There is only one assembly that references the plugin of concerndirectly as part of an autofac registration of it (code snippet at the very end).

```
[ImportingConstructor]
public SpellCheckPlugin(
    IPluginSettingsProvider settingsProvider,
    ISpellingService spellingService,
    ISpellCheckProviderFactory spellCheckProviderFactory)
```

There is only 1 implementation of `ISpellingService`

```
[Export(typeof(ISpellingService))]
public class SpellingService : ISpellingService
```

This is an open source [Code52 project on github](https://github.com/Code52/DownmarkerWPF).

The plugin import is:

```
[ImportMany]
IEnumerable<IPlugin> plugins;
```

**What I've tried so far:**

1. [This](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2010/05/03/mef-deploymentcatalog-and-reference-assemblies/) and [this blog](http://geekswithblogs.net/abhijeetp/archive/2011/10/30/mef-101---part-2.aspx) post make reference to using `[ImportMany(AllowRecomposition = true)]` but that also doesn't seem to help.
2. Other discussions I found mention setting the 'Copy Local' to false, but because it's actually used in registration code that's not an option, as it doesn't end up in the output folder.

**Any ideas?**

The registration code referencing the plug-in

```
builder.RegisterType<SpellingService>().As<ISpellingService>()
    .SingleInstance()
    .OnActivating(args =>
{
    var settingsService = args.Context.Resolve<ISettingsProvider>();
    var settings = settingsService.GetSettings<SpellCheckPlugin.SpellCheckPluginSettings>();
    args.Instance.SetLanguage(settings.Language);
})
```

Comment: `AllowRecomposition = true` does not apply to constructor injected composition. Are you using .Net 4.5: e.g. `builder.RegisterType<...>`. This looks like the enhanced conventional model in 4.5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Solution

The problem was a bug where the current assembly via `GetExecutingAssembly` was being used in the PluginManager() as one of the catalog entries in the `AggregateCatalog` being supplied to the `CompositionContainer`.

```
var catalog = new AggregateCatalog();

// This was causing the composition to detect additional imports
catalog.Catalogs.Add(new AssemblyCatalog(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()));
```

This bug came about from extracting out the services/plug-ins into their own assemblies, which were originally part of the core MarkPad assembly.

> Credit goes to [@shiftkey](https://twitter.com/shiftkey) and this [patch](https://github.com/shiftkey/DownmarkerWPF/commit/7be3668fecae7fe168a79d0759c20004ada89854).

#### Extra Improvements

As part of this patch there was some extra clean-up that might be useful to support this answer.

Since the SpellCheckPlugin took interfaces, the exports were simply moved to the interfaces themselves not the concrete types.

```
[ImportingConstructor]
public SpellCheckPlugin(
    IPluginSettingsProvider settingsProvider,
    ISpellingService spellingService,
    ISpellCheckProviderFactory spellCheckProviderFactory)
```

Adding Export on Interfaces instead

```
[InheritedExport]
public interface ISpellCheckProviderFactory

// and

[InheritedExport]
public interface ISpellingService
```

Removing concrete exports

```
[Export(typeof(ISpellingService))]
public class SpellingService : ISpellingService

// and

[Export(typeof(ISpellCheckProviderFactory))]
public class SpellCheckProviderFactory : ISpellCheckProviderFactory
```

Comment: You are my new hero and a lot of love goes out to @shiftkey too.